# How can I decode a JSON array with multiple data types?

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to decode a JSON file from an [API](http://madlibz.herokuapp.com/api/random) that I want to use but the `value` array contains a bunch of strings and an int at the end. When I specify the data type in the struct as AnyObject, it says that the struct does not conform to the Decodable protocol. Am I missing something? Is there a way I can fetch the data without the last Int?
[image: JSON API Call result]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/swift) to parse the model data from JSON.

```
// MARK: - DataModel
struct DataModel: Codable {
    let title: String
    let blanks: [String]
    let value: [Value]
}

enum Value: Codable {
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .integer(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Value.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for Value"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .integer(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}
```

Please use the following code to check the value type of `Value` below.

```
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let dataModel = try? JSONDecoder().decode(DataModel.self, from: jsonData)
dataModel?.value.forEach { value in
    switch value {
    case .integer(let intValue):
        print(intValue)
    case .string(let stringValue):
        print(stringValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Decodable` expects concrete types which conform to the protocol. `Any(Object)` is not supported.

You could decode `Value` as `UnkeyedContainer` *manually*. The result is the string array in `strings` and the integer value in `integer`.

```
struct DataModel: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let blanks: [String]
    let value: Value
}

struct Value: Decodable {
    let strings : [String]
    let integer : Int
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        var stringData = [String]()
        guard let numberOfItems = container.count else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container,
                                                   debugDescription: "Number of items in the array is unknown")
        }
        while container.currentIndex < numberOfItems - 1 {
            stringData.append(try container.decode(String.self))
        }
        strings = stringData
        integer = try container.decode(Int.self)
    }
}
```

Side note: A JSON value is never an **object** (reference type).

Comment: is there an advantage in working with the `currentIndex` and item count rather than the container's `isAtEnd` property?

Comment: I don't think so , but it's an alternative to avoid the `do - catch` block and especially in this case where the integer value is at the last index.